# Javascript/jQuery - IF in array and IF value:pair

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a numeric **value:pair** list as follows:

```
var level1 = {0:1,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:0,1:1,2:1,3:1,4:1,5:1};
```

...if I rewrite it into an array like this (which will lose it's numeric format):

```
var level1 = ['0:1','1:0','2:0','3:0','4:0','5:0','6:0','1:1','2:1','3:1','4:1','5:1'];
```

...I can check if the value is such array exist by:

```
if($.inArray(value, level1) > -1)
{
    // let's party    
}
```

**How would I check if the numeric value:pair exists for the value:pair list above?**

Comment: `if (level1[0] == 1)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first example you use JavaScript *object*, not array. So to check whether element with `value` name exists and equals to `pair` use:

```
if (level1[value] === pair) {
    // ...
}
```

But you should also note, that object properties are unique. It means that there can't be several properties with the same name in object, like `{ a: 1, b: 2, a: 3 }` -- it will finally result in `{ a: 3, b: 2 }`. So in your case it is better to use array.

**READ MORE:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean exactly; if you mean to search for a value:pair exactly then VisioN's solution is perfect. But suppose you do not want to check whether e.g. the pair `2:0` exists, but you want to get a list of all entries in `level1` that start with `2` you can use:

```
level1.filter(function(v){ return v[0] === '2'; })
```